# Swift: Is Array<Float> the same as [Float]?

Tags: swift, swift2

They seem to be the same. Or is there a hidden difference?

```
import Foundation

var a: Array<Float> = Array<Float>()
var b: [Float]

a.append(1.22)
a.append(3.44)

b = a
```

This compiles and runs without any warnings or errors.

Comment: Perhaps because [Float] is shorthand notation for an array of Float's?

Comment: its exactly same no difference , I know this from one of the ios stanford lectures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes `[Type]` is syntactic sugar for `Array<Type>`. Similarly, dictionaries have `[Key:Value]` for `Dictionary<Key, Value>`.

So you can use `[Float]` in any place where `Array<Float>` is expected, including variable/property declaration and instantiation.

Syntactic sugar is widely used in Swift. One of the most used cases is the `?` modifier which makes a type optional:

```
var string: String?
```

In fact, this is actually an enum:

```
var string: Optional<String>
```

Answer (score 4):

The syntax `[Float]` is just short version of `Array<Float>` so it's the same but in your code the line:

```
var a: Array<Float> = Array<Float>()
```

also initialise the array to empty one (equivallent to `[Float]()`) but the line

```
var b: [Float]
```

just declare b as an array of floats without initialisation.